# p:carousel doesn't fire on Internet Explorer 10 after themes were removed from web.xml

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-10

My problem was presented after the PrimeFaces themes were removed from web.xml, when I use Internet Explorer 10 the [`<p:carousel>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/carousel.xhtml) does not move but in Chrome or FireFox, this is fine.

Thanks by advance.

PD: I am using prmiefaces 4.0 and JSF 2.0

My web.xml contain the following lines

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Do you have the code up somewhere that we can see with/without the web.xml file?

Comment: Do you see some JavaScript errors on the js console? If it does not move, some JavaScript errors are supposed.

Comment: @Tiny in the IE console show me that: HTML1406: Inicio de etiqueta no válido: "<?". Los signos de pregunta no deben iniciar etiquetas. 
redesSociales_1.xhtml, Línea 1 Carácter 2

Comment: @tobint you can find my web.xml in http://www.xmlplayground.com/BDq2aS

Comment: Google Translate : "*HTML1406: Home invalid tag: "<?". The question marks should not initiate labels. redesSociales_1.xhtml, Line 1 Character 2*". Does it mean like that?

Comment: @Tiny these lines appears in the IE console, but I don't know what it mean

Comment: Switch your development environment to English. English error messages yield so much better search results in Google and Stack Overflow.